# Trouble With PHP Function, passing arguments

Tags: php, function

```
<?php
function setFont($text, $name, $size){
 return "<div style='font-family: ".$name.";font-size: ".$size."'>".$text."</div>";
}

echo setFont("Hello", "tahoma", "19")
echo setFont("Welcome", "tahoma", "19")
?>
```

What's the trouble with my Function?

Comment: There is no trouble with function. No syntax errors in function. Not really sure what your problem is (I mean, I AM sure, but YOU don't said what you want to get, what you get and what problem is :P). Only syntax error there is is outside function. Each `echo` needs `;` at the end of line

Comment: What error you get? What do you expect the function should do?

Comment: Trouble is that there's no `;` after first call

Comment: Please edit the php code!

Comment: Please READ YOUR ERROR.... jeez. You said nothing about what your problem is, just posted random code and expect us to be slaves. And you didn't even tried to check what error is...

Comment: Plus, tons of people blindly answered already with fixing 4 mistakes in your code.. so yeah..

Comment: It gives a white page!

Comment: look in your error log....

Comment: Just as @Eugen said, or add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at beginning of your code. Or modify `httpd.conf` file in your server config if you have access to

Comment: I got thousand answers `;` was not there. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function setFont($text, $name, $size){
 return "<div style='font-family: $name ;font-size: $size'>".$text."</div>";
}

echo setFont("Hello", "tahoma", "19");
echo setFont("Welcome", "tahoma", "19");
?>
```

Comment: Hello, I've edited the forgotten strings. But it's not my trouble!

Comment: Then enlighten us what your trouble is.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function setFont($text, $name, $size){
 return "<div style='font-family:$name;font-size:".$size."px'>".$text."</div>";
}

echo setFont("Hello", "tahoma", "19");
echo setFont("Welcome", "tahoma", "19");
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, This is the way

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function setFont($text, $name, $size){
return "<div style='font-family: ".$name.";font-size: ".$size."'>".$text."</div>";
}

echo setFont("Hello", "tahoma", "19");
echo setFont("Welcome", "tahoma", "19");
```

?>